# Update the value in database after day change

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a field in database table, let say, Counter.
Initially its value is 0. After every transaction, the value is incremented by 1.
But at the end of day I want to update this value to 0 again.

e.g. If we have total 10 transactions in a day, the counter will be 10 offcourse. I want that Counter to be 0 again at 12 am every day.

Thanks

Comment: Have you taken a look at [sql server jobs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx) ?

Comment: nops.. let me check that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can Create a Job for that..

For More information visit
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx

Comment: I have created a Job by using both stored procedure and query, but its not working, there is also no error. Is there any method to check whether Job is executing or not ??

Answer (score -1):

You can write a stored procedure for resetting the counter, hang it on the **Job** in **SQL Server Agent**, and then set a **schedule** that suits you